# Why must all the data in a storage device be lost when its file system is changed?

Tags: filesystems

I know these things about storage devices:

- They're separated into two parts: the file table and the file data
- The way these work is dictated by the file system
- All file systems have a file table and file data
- The file table can be changed without changing the file data, and vice versa
- A file can be removed from the file table for a quick delete without actually removing the file's data

So, my question is: **when you change the file system on (or "format") a drive, why must all the file data be lost?** Can't a computer simply remember the file table and re-create it in the format of the new system?

I'm sure you'd run into some issues with a completely full drive if the new file system requires a larger table than the old system, but other than that, I don't see why this can't be done.

I also know that after a "quick format" (where just the file table is replaced, but the new one is empty) that all the file data is still there and can be recovered with forensic tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that there are two separated, well-defined areas on a storage device: the "file table" (metadata) and the "file data" (data), so you could keep the data area untouched while the metadata area is erased and re-created.

That's not the case. Not only does each filesystem put its fixed metadata in a different place, but also on most filesystems part of the metadata is mixed with the data. This often happens with directories, which are internally treated in a way somewhat similar to a "special file".

For instance, you have FAT32 with its metadata area at the beginning of the storage device, plus directories mixed with the data; NTFS, which IIRC has its main metadata area (the MFT) in a fixed location in the middle of the storage device; the ext family (ext2, ext3, ext4) which splits the storage device in "block groups", each with its own metadata in fixed locations, so you have several metadata areas spread all over the storage device, plus directories stored as special files; and btrfs, which uses a tree structure in which most of the metadata can be almost anywhere.

As you can see, what is data in one filesystem might overlap with what is metadata in another filesystem. To convert from one filesystem to another, not only would the conversion tool have to convert the directory structure, but it would also have to move part of the data out of the way. This can be done (see for instance [a conversion from ext3/ext4 to btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Conversion_from_Ext3)), but since it's complex and rarely done (most storage devices are formatted once with one filesystem and keep using it for the rest of its life), there's not much incentive to implement it (and test it, which is somewhat important when dealing with your user's data).

Comment: " most storage devices are formatted once with one filesystem and keep using it for the rest of its life" do you have any data on this? I feel like USB drives and micro SD cards are formatted much more often

Answer (score 2):

> They're separated into two parts: the file table and the file data

Semi-true, in practice most filesystems will store some metadata in fixed locations and other metadata as "special files". Exactly what metadata is stored where will depend on the filesystem.

Often the fixed locations are not all at the start but are spread through the storage volume in some way.

> So, my question is: when you change the file system on (or "format") a drive, why must all the file data be lost? Can't a computer simply remember the file table and re-create it in the format of the new system?

Converting a file-system in-place is tricky for several reasons.

1. The layout of the metadata is almost certainly going to be different, this basically means you need to keep all the old metadata around until all the new metadata has been generated.
2. The metadata may be too large to store in memory. So simply reading all the old metadata and then writing out all the new based on the in-memory copy is not a good option.
3. Most filesystems store significant metadata at fixed locations. This means that for many conversions a tool cannot simply create the new metadata "in the gaps" left by the old data/metadata.
4. The data itself may be stored in a different manner, for example on NTFS clusters are always aligned whereas on FAT they need not be. Some filesystems may compress data.

None of these problems are insurmountable but they mean that writing a filesystem converter is a difficult job and that running it often carries a non-negligable risk of data loss.

I am aware of the following converters.

- Windows 98 and ME come with a converter that can convert from FAT16 to FAT32. In windows 98 this is readily visible but afaict in windows ME they made it command line only.
- Windows 2000 and later come with a converter that can convert from FAT16 and FAT32 to NTFS. Again this converter is command line only. Also AIUI the conversion process sometimes results in 512 byte clusters due to the alignment issue I mentioned above.
- The tools for BTRFS come with a program that can convert ext2/3/4 to BTRFS.
- There is a tool out there for Linux called fstransform, the readme claims it supports  ext2, ext3, ext4 and reiserfs. It appears to use some tricks with sparse files to get the filesystem drivers in the kernel to do the heavy lifting and so can in-theory work with any Linux filesystem that supports certain features. Apparently there is also some experimental support for NTFS ( https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform/issues/1 ).

Comment: Thanks! It's also worth noting that the iOS 10.3 and macOS 10.13 installers both transitioned the primary SSD from HFS+ to APFS

Answer (score 0):

> when you change the file system on (or "format") a drive, why must all the file data be lost?

It doesn't have to be. Normally formatting a drive is done to initialize a new drive with no data or discard the data that was on it.

Should you have a storage media with data on it you could easily change the file system structure from one to another (e.g. FAT -> ext3) in any number of ways. This is not done very often by end users nor in multi-user environments. The approach varies depending on details you did not provide. Note that not all your assumptions are necessarily valid.

To learn more about file systems checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystems.

Comment: Cool! How would one go about doing so?

Comment: I never have. I rarely change file systems on a device that is in use; if I had to then I would back-up the volume, change the file-system, and restore the volume.

Comment: Converting from FAT to NTFS with preservation of data is supported out-of-the-box by Windows. I used it a couple of times on systems that were installed on a FAT partition.